# VueJS Router - change named view in root with child route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

**The ask**

1. Control a root-level view from a child route. The example below is one level deep, but I could need to control the `other` view from deeper routes.
2. Have both the default view and another view in a single template, `other` simply must live at this level and will not work how I need if nested within other components:

   `<router-view name="default"/>`

   `<router-view name="other">/>`
3. Must have a parent-child route relationship to maintain navigation functionality (router-link-active)

**Attempts**

For a route, have the view set:

```
{
    path: '/my-path',
    component: ComponentOne,
}
```

Going to `/my-path` shows ComponentOne in `default` view, `other` view is empty, **as it should**.

Now at a child route, I want the `other` view to show ComponentTwo.

This does not work because it expects `other` view to be within `default` view, and so ComponentTwo is simply not rendered:

```
{
    path: '/my-path',
    component: ComponentOne,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/my-path/more', 
            components: {
                'other': ComponentTwo
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not work because it does not maintain the parent-child relationship:

```
{
    path: '/my-path',
    component: ComponentOne
}, 
{
    path: '/my-path/more',
    components: {
        default: ComponentOne, 
        other: ComponentTwo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Leonardi's solution does not work if you wanted to refer to the the current child's component from a component that's more than 1 level higher in the hierarchy (i.e. a layout).

I was able to work around this by writing a computed method to determine the component of the current child route in the parent component.

```js
{
    path: '/my-path',
    component: ComponentOne,
    children: [
        {
            path: '/my-path/more', 
            components: {
                'other': ComponentTwo
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```html
<!-- App.vue or SomeLayout.vue -->
<template>
  <router-view /> <!-- ComponentOne -->
  <component :is="componentOfCurrentChildRoute" /> <!-- ComponentTwo -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    componentOfCurrentChildRoute() {
      // Get an array of the current route ancestor hierarchy
      const {matched} = this.$route;

      // Return the component defined by the current child route
      return matched?.[matched.length - 1]?.component; // or components.sidebar if using named views
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Does it have some side effects to replace <router-view> by <component>?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to control a router-view from a nested route.
However, to do what you ask quickly, the solution would be to manage the contents of all (`/my-path` and `sub-routes`), in a nested route even for the path `/my-path` as well. You don't even need named routes.

I'll explain better with an example:

```
{
    path: '/my-path',
    component: ComponentWrapper,
    children: [
        {
            path: '', // Match '/my-path' or '/my-path/'
            component: ComponentOne
        },
        {
            path: 'more', '/my-path/more'
            component: ComponentTwo
        }
    ]
}
```

In the `ComponentWrapper` you have to insert a router-view to render the nested routes and everything will work fine, even parent-child route relationship.